# Building a case for a server

Tags: case, wiring

I want to order a RasPi soon, because it is very interesting. Well, I informed me about the RasPi and now I know: I want definitly a RasPi. 
Now, I have a older case of a 3.5" external enclosure, which I don't need anymore. I thought: I can use it to hold the external USB drive and the RasPi itself. The case already have a hole in a size of a default LAN-jack. I might need to take the RasPi out of the case, when I want to test or do something else with the RasPi. Now the problem: How should I wiring the LAN-jack to my RasPi? I don't think that frickling with a cutted piece of LAN-cable would be a good method. So, what do you think? How could I create a good wiring?

Comment: Sorry but please ask a specific question. I am very happy you are interested in the Pi- But what are you asking. exactly? How to wire the LAN, how to build a case or what? Please edit your question and make it more precise. The title does not match your question!??! COnfusing...

Answer (score 1):

There are a range of pre-made RasPi cases on the market, as covered in [This article](http://www.geek.com/chips/11-best-raspberry-pi-cases-1530907/). I bought a clear one from [element14](http://au.element14.com/jsp/search/browse.jsp?N=2101%20204381&Ntk=gensearch&Ntt=raspberry%20pi%20case&Ntx=mode%20matchallpartial) a while back but they have since gone up in price, [adafruit](http://www.adafruit.com/category/105) also stocks a range of RasPi accessories but if you look around you can probably find a local distributor close to where you are.

Comment: I want to create cheap media server - so, i cannot buy a preassembled case, because they are too expensive. Also I want to add a usb disk to it, so my already existing case is perfect. I already seen doubled LAN adapters, which I could buy, but they cost $19! A way expensive!

Answer (score 0):

Got any LEGO bricks laying around?  Plenty of people are using them for building Pi cases.  And then you can add room for drives, usb devices, etc. And there is no need for an adapter, just place the Pi up against the edge of your case and leave an opening for the cable.

Answer (score 0):

I just grabbed a audio cassette box and cut the needed slots using a small saw.
I recommend to glue some tape on the cutting zones, not only to mark the cutting places, but also to helps to avoid breaking the plastic when cutting.

Its a simple case, but easy to build and manage. grab a transparent cassette box and you have a pretty case for free!

This is not my case, but its a reference::
http://diogenesclubarchives.blogspot.pt/2012/10/thinking-inside-box.html

Answer (score 0):

Well, this IS my case, but I think higuita has an excellent idea to use tape to protect the edges of the plastic when cutting holes in the audio cassette case. I used a Dremel tool and it did not take a lot of time or skill. Just a willingness to sacrifice a Peter Frampton cassette.

http://diogenesclubarchives.blogspot.pt/2012/10/thinking-inside-box.html